# Close an old question of a duplicate I just asked?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I've managed to find what is, essentially, an earlier version of a question I just asked. However, I think my question is written (marginally) better.

Should I vote to close/delete my own question as the dupe, or vote to close the older question (seems a bit mean on the original poster!)?

The questions are [Can Netbeans run projects in specific VMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491277/can-netbeans-run-projects-in-specific-vms) (my question) and [Configure Netbeans to compile and run different jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749341/configure-netbeans-to-compile-and-run-different-jvm) (older question).

(As I write this, neither question has any answers.)

Comment: I don't think you can close answerless questions as duplicates anymore except in some specific cases.  I'd just say leave them both be.  If you do get an answer, then you can VtC the older one as a dup of yours.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Just to clarify/confirm, you can't vote to close a question as a duplicate of an answerless question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the older question isn't answered, then you *can't* vote to close either question as a duplicate until the other has an answer.  If you're willing to actively pursue an answer to your question (by replying to answers and clarifying comments, posting what you've tried, etc.), then you have the advantage over an old, abandoned, unanswered question.  Once you have an acceptable answer, one that you think answers the old question as well, go ahead and vote to close the original question as a duplicate of your own.  The goal is for people who search for an answer to the problem to *find an answer*.  The old question isn't doing that.

---

Note: I'm assuming good faith here, based on my read of both questions.  Yours is quite a bit more than just *marginally* better.  Once you've posted the question I think it's ok to go ahead and pursue getting it answered.  If you do find an unanswered original question *before* posting your question, you should consider editing it to include details left out by the original poster (if you can do that without fundamentally changing the question). This will bump it to the front page and hopefully still get an answer for you and the OP.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. You can assume good faith - I've been an SO member almost since the beginning, but with only 400 rep I think you can assume if I'm a rep tart then I'm not a very good one :-)

Comment: Although with 400 rep I also can't vote to close someone else's question anyway! D'oh! I do have a reasonable answer to my own question, though, so I'll leave other people to decide if/how to tidy up. Thanks, again.

Comment: @RobGilliam The "assuming good faith" bit was more about people *knowingly* posting duplicates than about any kind of rep farming shenanigans.  I just didn't want anyone using my first paragraph above as an excuse to post duplicate questions when there's a perfectly fine original.  (Which is not the case in your example.)